# Différence entre « de-ci de-là » et « par-ci par-là »

Tags: vocabulaire, locutions, indications-de-lieu

Je voudrais savoir quelle est la différence entre de-ci de-là et par-ci par-là.

Comment: A ma connaissance, il n'y en a aucune, si ce n'est que de-ci de-là est peut être un peu plus formel.

Comment: @LaurentS. Oui, plus littéraire et poétique, comme l'est encore plus *de-ça, de-là*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En fait, la réponse est toute simple, ils ont la même signification. Ce sont des variantes orthographiques toutes les deux. On pourrait même affirmer qu'il s'agit de synonymes et qu'ils se définissent l'un et l'autre.

Je dirais que « de-ci de-là » se retrouve généralement plus en poésie.

Par pure curiosité intellectuelle, cette expression peut prendre différentes traductions si nous retournons aux racines latines, cependant elle garde toujours le même sens.

Une traduction possible pourrait être : "inde huc atque illuc" ce qui également prendre cette traduction brute et littéraire : "viendrait de là à un lieu quelconque".